# Restoring database back up

Tags: sql, backup, restore

I want to restore a backup from another server to my personal computer, unfortunately i can't 
restore the backup. what should i do?

error message:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

```
Restore failed for Server 'MOHI-PC'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
```

For help, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1%20((KJ_RTM).100402-1540%20)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore%20Server&LinkId=20476).

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: File 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\sgdb.mdf' is claimed by 'SGinv_Data'(12) and 'SgDb_dat'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
```

For help, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=10.50.1600.1%20((KJ_RTM).100402-1540%20)&LinkId=20476).

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the names of the files as well as potentially renaming the db just to rule out more options. If it continues occurring that should at least narrow down one more thing.

Comment: thanks for your help;
{
    the back up file was contain more than one mdf file and in the "restore as"  coloumn all names was same as each other. i renamed the pathes and the bakup file restored successfully.
}

messagebox.show("HOOOOOOOOOOORA")